# How to set custom response decoder to feign?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, polling, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm using *feign* with *OkHttpClient* and I want to use the retry mechanism to do short polling on an endpoint that returns status code 200 ok and empty body.
Is that possible using *feign*?
the custom error decoder isn't being called on status code 2xx.
Any other preferred way to do short polling? btw I'm using *Kotlin*.

Comment: If `errorDecoder` is not called, then maybe it's possible to use `decoder` for this? If the body is empty throw `RetryableException`, otherwise, delegate processing to the default decoder.

Comment: I thought so as well but couldn't find any example, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following step to your `Feign.builder()`:

```kotlin
    .decoder(object : Decoder {
        private val delegate = Decoder.Default() //Or whatever decoder you actually use
        override fun decode(response: Response, type: Type) {
            if (response.status() == 200 && (response.body() == null || response.body().length() == 0))
                throw RetryableException(
                    response.status(),
                    "Response body was empty",
                    response.request().httpMethod(),
                    null, //retry interval will be determined by Retryer
                    response.request()
                )
            else delegate.decode(response, type)
        }
    })
```

Comment: I'm using the OkHttpClient so I don't have that builder.

Comment: You've said, you're using _feign with OkHttpClient_. This builder is a part of [feign-okhttp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-okhttp) package. It accepts `OkHttpClient` as a parameter of `client` builder method: `Feign.builder().client(OkHttpClient()).decoder(...)`